# Open Google Maps App iOS 6 (web App)

Tags: ios, html, google-maps, protocols

Is there any protocol that I can use to open an address in the (now downloadable) Google Maps? This is not a native app, just a web app/site for Safari (web clip). Does Google provide any such protocol for use on a non-native app? I know how to accomplish this for the Apple maps app (with the maps://), but does Google provide any way for doing this for their Google maps app?

Thank A LOT in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe so, the URL would be (comgooglemaps://...)

see this article for more information-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Comment: Of note, the URL scheme documented in the above link ONLY works for iOS. If an Android user somehow finds your web app/site and clicks the link, nothing will happen. Just an FYI.